# Add typing for a staticmethod in a python class

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

In a class `Foo` I link a static method in a class variable to subclass that class later and just exchange that function with another. The class contains some methods which call this exchangable function. The code below does not produce any mypy issues.

```py
def some_function(text: str) -> None:
    print(text)

class Foo:
    _some_func: ClassVar[staticmethod] = staticmethod(some_function)

    def some_method(self, text: str) -> None:
        self._some_func(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Foo().some_method("Hello World!")
```

Now, I am trying to improve my typing, so I want to use a callback protocol to actually add typing for `Foo._some_func`. I have created the following protocol class:

```py
class SomeFuncProtocol(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, __text: str) -> None:
        ...
```

It does work as long as I use `_some_func: ClassVar[SomeFuncProtocol] = some_function`, but I can't find a way to use staticmethod and the protocol class for typing. I wish for something like the following, but mypy tells me that `staticmethod` does not expect a type argument.

```py
class Foo:
   _some_func: ClassVar[staticmethod[SomeFuncProtocol]] = staticmethod(some_function)
   ...
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't put the function into the class directly and `@staticmethod` it? Since you access the field through ``self``, there actually isn't even a point in restricting it to ``staticmethod``.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. The function is a function from a set of functions in a package which take all the same parameters but return different values. My plan is to subclass `Foo` and just exchange the function in `_some_func`. And since these functions don't take `self` as the first parameter, I have to use `staticmethod()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stuck with similar thing for a while, here's what worked for me:

```py
from typing import ClassVar, Protocol

def some_function(text: str) -> None:
    print(text)

class SomeFuncProtocol(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, __text: str) -> None:
        return

class Foo:
   _some_func: ClassVar[SomeFuncProtocol] = staticmethod(some_function)

Foo._some_func('a')
Foo()._some_func('a')
Foo._some_func = some_function
Foo()._some_func = some_function  # E: Cannot assign to class variable "_some_func" via instance
```

The code above typechecks (except for last line that is intentionally incorrect).

You don't need `staticmethod` in type annotation: it's a function that (simplified) takes callable as argument and returns another callable with same signature, but with explicit sign that it doesn't accept `self`. So return type of `staticmethod` is the same callable, we can express it like this:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar
_C = TypeVar('_C', bound=Callable[..., Any])
def staticmethod(func: _C) -> _C: ...
```

You can try it in [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=d2bc0f11d8ed8f5426b36685960c265d).

Comment: This was my initial solution which kept giving me `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "staticmethod", variable has type "SomeFuncProtocol")`.  I discovered this issue is only thrown with mypy < 0.930. I've updated and it fixed the issue. Thank you.